# ofstream file does not write

Tags: c++, ofstream

I tried to write my own method to save a `Eigen::MatrixXd` object in a textfile. However, the file is empty after running this method. While debugging, I saw that the file does not open as I want. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include<Eigen\Dense>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void savematrix(Eigen::MatrixXd matrix, string filename) {
    int m = matrix.rows();
    int n = matrix.cols();
    ofstream file(filename, ofstream::trunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < m, i++;) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n, j++;) {
            file << m << ";" << n << ";" << matrix(i, j) << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(2, 2);
    A(0, 0) = 0;
    A(1, 0) = 1;
    A(0, 1) = 1;
    A(1, 1) = 0;
    cout << A << endl;
    savematrix(A, "savematrixtest.txt");
}
```

Comment: You made a typo in both of your `for` loops. Please look at the examples in your C++ textbook of basic `for` loops, compare it with your code, and you should be able to easily see the typos.

Comment: Btw: You can also just do `file << matrix` since Eigen provides an overloaded `operator<<`. If you have special formatting needs please have a look at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1IOFormat.html

Comment: @dtell I know that, but somehow I have a project which crushes when using BDCSVD. Then, I tried to save the matrix which it crushed on and loaded it and applied SVD and it worked. So, I wanted to write my own methods to check that nothing gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a typo a for loop should have looked like that

```
for( int i = 0; i < m; i++){}
```

I did not think of it as my compiler did not give me an error.

Comment: Just because the compiler did not report an error doesn't mean that your program will be correct. All it means that it is syntactically correct. Sit down a bunch of monkeys in front of keyboards, and eventually they'll bang away something that will be a syntactically valid C++ program.

Comment: As you have noticed, all three semicolon-separated parameters of the for loop are optional, and you can have several comma-separated statements in each of these.

Comment: Please, dont answer your own question after being told that this is not related to Eigen, but a typo in your C++ code. This question and this answer will be no useful for anyone.